# How to ignore or skip a test method using RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, selenium-webdriver, rspec2

please guide how to disable one of the below test methods using RSpec. I am using Selenuim WebDriver + RSpec combinations to run tests.

```
require 'rspec'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

describe 'Automation System' do

  before(:each) do    
    ###
  end

  after(:each) do
    @driver.quit
  end

  it 'Test01' do
      #positive test case
  end

  it 'Test02' do
      #negative test case
  end    
end
```

Comment: I found [Programmatically skip a test in RSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57797745/6243352) relevant even though it's not a suitable dupe target. You can use `around` hooks and call `example.skip` on a condition.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use [`pending()`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/pending/pending-examples) or change `it` to `xit` or wrap assert in pending block for wait implementation:

```
describe 'Automation System' do

  # some code here

  it 'Test01' do
     pending("is implemented but waiting")
  end

  it 'Test02' do
     # or without message
     pending
  end

  pending do
    "string".reverse.should == "gnirts"
  end

  xit 'Test03' do
     true.should be(true)
  end    
end
```

Comment: Also, you can change `scenario` to `xscenario` too :)

Comment: Turns out `xcontext` & `xdescribe` also works :)

Answer (score 19):

Another way to skip tests:

```
# feature test
scenario 'having js driver enabled', skip: true do
  expect(page).to have_content 'a very slow test'
end

# controller spec
it 'renders a view very slow', skip: true do
  expect(response).to be_very_slow
end
```

source: [rspec 3.4 documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/command-line/tag-option)

Answer (score 10):

Pending and skip are nice but I've always used this for larger describe/context blocks that I needed to ignore/skip.

```
describe Foo do
  describe '#bar' do
    it 'should do something' do
      ...
    end

    it 'should do something else' do
      ...
    end
  end
end if false
```

Comment: This is really undersold as a solution to this problem.  No it's not the most clear approach, but it's really effective.

Comment: Bonus here is that it does NOT print pending and you can have bad code inside the example

Answer (score 9):

Here is an alternate solution to ignore (skip) the above test method (say, `Test01`) from sample script.

```
describe 'Automation System' do

  # some code here

  it 'Test01' do
     skip "is skipped" do
     ###CODE###
     end
  end

  it 'Test02' do
     ###CODE###         
  end    
end
```

Comment: I like this one. Semantically, "skip" "xit" and "pending" are different things

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of alternatives for this. Mainly marking it as `pending` or `skipped` and there is a subtle difference between them. From the docs

> An example can either be marked as skipped, in which is it not executed, or pending in which it is executed but failure will not cause a failure of the entire suite.

Refer the docs here:

- https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/pending-and-skipped-examples/pending-examples
- https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/pending-and-skipped-examples/skip-examples

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to skip a specific block of code from being running while testing.

Example : Using xit in place of it.

```
  it "redirects to the index page on success" do
    visit "/events"
  end
```

Change the above block of code to below.

```
xit "redirects to the index page on success" do #Adding x before it will skip this test.
    visit "/event"
end
```

Second way: By calling pending inside the block.
Example:

```
 it "should redirects to the index page on success" do 
  pending                             #this will be skipped
    visit "/events" 
end
```