# Programmatically skip a test in RSpec

Tags: ruby, specifications

I am curious if there is a way to skip a test in RSpec in a before block? I am thinking something like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do |spec|
    if some_condition?
      spec.skip
    end
  end
end
```

The above call to `skip` does not work. This is for an idea I am working on, so it's important that it works this way and not have to modify the test with metadata for instance. I imagine it's possible using RSpec internals, for instance tagging the status, but I wanted to check first to see if there is any API for this.

Comment: You could  [`break`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402757/how-to-break-out-from-a-ruby-block) out of the block

Comment: That does not work, just tried. By that I mean that it does exit the before block but the example still runs.

Comment: I see, then you could use [`pending()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288775/how-to-ignore-or-skip-a-test-method-using-rspec) to suspend the test.

Comment: That doesn't do it either, I already went through the options listed online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked in the rspec mailing list, and it turns out `skip 'reason'` does the trick. The example is marked as pending, which is not ideal, but that answers the question.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have to explicitly call the skip inside the block:

```
around(:each) do |example|
  if some_condition?
    example.run
  else
    example.skip
  end
end
```

Documentation for [around hooks](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/hooks/around-hooks)

Turns the example into a "pending" (skips it, prints output differently, etc)

Comment: Does not work, as expected since this will surely run the example regardless.

Comment: I updated my comment with a working example that I tested. Call `example.skip` to skip a spec, `example.run` to run it